# Reading RSS with Syndication Feed and XMLReader in Windows Phone 7

Tags: .net, rss, windows-phone, xmlreader, syndication-feed

Hi I want to read the following Rss in Windows Phone. I can read the common items such as title with the Syndication Feed. But I'm unable to read the elements like  from that. I have tried some codes too. But they didn't work. Here's the RSS.

```
<title>Title of the feed </title>
<pubDate>Thu, 22 Nov 2010 22:15:04 +0000</pubDate>
<guid isPermaLink="false"><![CDATA[2c864c4ffasfasfasfasfaer54854738422711]]></guid>
<link><![CDATA[http://abc.ldfan.com/something something something]]></link>
<media:thumbnail url="http://abc.ldfan.com/item/2137111" />
<description><![CDATA[<p>some descriptions jsdfoasjf saifjoeij alfoer alfmaoeijfea9 a epfa3- fasfa039ur aelmf320jaofa </p>]]></description>
<enclosure length="9113657" type="audio/mpeg" url="http://abc.ldfan.com/eslasdfast/song.mp3" />
<itunes:duration>12:39</itunes:duration>
<itunes:explicit>no</itunes:explicit>
<itunes:keywords />
<itunes:subtitle><![CDATA[ome descriptions jsdfoasjf saifjoeij alfoer alfmaoeijfea9 a epfa3- fasfa039ur aelmf320jaofa ]]></itunes:subtitle>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What code works to read the title of the feed?

Comment: foreach (SyndicationItem f in feeds.Items)
                    { string title = f.Title;}

Answer (score 0):

What property are you trying to get?  Looking at the [SyndicationItem documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationitem%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), to get something standard (like pubDate), you can use

```
foreach (SyndicationItem f in feeds.Items)
{
    DateTime pubDate = f.PublishDate;
}
```

and for something nonstandard (like itunes:subtitle), you can use

```
foreach (SyndicationItem f in feeds.Items)
{
    string subtitle = f.AttributeExtensions[new XmlQualifiedName("subtitle", "itunes")];
}
```

See also the [Loosely-Typed Extensions Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943475.aspx).

Comment: Greg, I don't know the reason, but it didn't work. I tried some examples in the link too. But no luck. I tried according to your second cord block to get extensions. But it prompts me to handle the "KeyNotFound" exception and when I handled that it gives me that key was not found... Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the full RSS file?  It's possible that the "itunes" namespace is defined as something else above, and that's what you should be using as the second argument to the XmlQualifiedName constructor.

Comment: @gregstoll Thanks for providing guidance on this. I think you want "ElementExtensions" instead of "AttributeExtesions" though.

Comment: Also, FYI, if you want to get the itunes tags the namespace is http:// www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd